# C++ Error: expected primary-expression before 'double'

Tags: c++

I need to write a class program that calculates the distance between two points - Point.cpp, and another class program that calls my Point.cpp program to calculate the length(basically distance from Point.cpp) and slope between two points - LineSegment.cpp. I tested my Point.cpp separately and it runs fine. But when I run everything together (in conjunction with the LineSegment.cpp), I get the following error message:

```
LineSegment.cpp: In member function ‘void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point)’:
LineSegment.cpp:31: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
LineSegment.cpp:32: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
LineSegment.cpp: In member function ‘void LineSegment::setEnd2(Point)’:
LineSegment.cpp:37: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
LineSegment.cpp:38: error: expected primary-expression before ‘double’
```

My codes are below.  I have marked the 4 lines that the error message refers to with a comment (everytime I posted my code with line numbers I received a suggested edit to take the line numbers out, so I did not include line numbers this time).

My guess is that I am calling the functions from Point.cpp incorrectly, but my textbook does not tell me how to call functions from a nested class.  Any guidance would be appreciated.  **Thank you all for your time!**

LineSegment.hpp

```
#ifndef LINESEGMENT_HPP
#define LINESEGMENT_HPP
#include "Point.hpp"

class LineSegment {
private:
   Point p1;
   Point p2;

public:
   LineSegment(Point, Point);
   void setEnd1(Point p1);
   void setEnd2(Point p2);
   Point getEnd1();
   Point getEnd2();
   double length();
   double slope();
};
#endif
```

LineSegment.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include "LineSegment.hpp"

//constructor
LineSegment::LineSegment(Point p1, Point p2) {
   setEnd1(p1);
   setEnd2(p2);
}

//set and get points
void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point p1) {
   p1.setXCoord(double);       // <-- error
   p1.setYCoord(double);       // <-- error
   setEnd1(p1);
}

void LineSegment::setEnd2(Point p2) {
   p2.setXCoord(double);       // <-- error
   p2.setYCoord(double);       // <-- error
   setEnd2(p2);
}

Point LineSegment::getEnd1() {
   return p1;
}

Point LineSegment::getEnd2() {
   return p2;
}

//calculations
double LineSegment::length() {
   return p1.distanceTo(p2);
}

double LineSegment::slope() {
   return(p2.getYCoord()-p1.getYCoord())/p2.getXCoord()-p1.getXCoord();
}
```

Point.hpp

```
#ifndef POINT_HPP
#define POINT_HPP
class Point {
private:
   double xCoord;
   double yCoord;

public:
   Point();
   Point(double x1, double y1);
   void setXCoord(double x1);
   void setYCoord(double y1);
   double getXCoord();
   double getYCoord();
   double distanceTo(const Point&);
};
#endif
```

Point.cpp

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "Point.hpp"

//default constructor
Point::Point() {
   xCoord = 0.0;
   yCoord = 0.0;
}

//constructor
Point::Point(double x, double y) {
   xCoord = x;
   yCoord = y;
}

//get and set functions
void Point::setXCoord(double x) {
   xCoord = x;
}

void Point::setYCoord(double y) {
  yCoord = y;
}

double Point::getXCoord() {
   return xCoord;
}

double Point::getYCoord() {
   return yCoord;
}

// calculate distance
double Point::distanceTo(const Point& p2) {
  double dx = p2.xCoord - xCoord;
  double dy = p2.yCoord - yCoord;
  return sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`double` is a type specifier not an object. And why does for example `setEnd1` call itself?

It seems you mean the following

```
//set and get points
void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point p1) {
   this->p1.setXCoord(p1.getXCoord());       // <-- error
   this->p1.setYCoord(pq.getYCoord());       // <-- error
}

void LineSegment::setEnd2(Point p2) {
   this->p2.setXCoord(p2.getXCoord());       // <-- error
   this->p2.setYCoord(p2.getXCoord());       // <-- error
}
```

You could write even simpler

```
//set and get points
void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point p1) {
   this->p1 = p1;
}

void LineSegment::setEnd2(Point p2) {
   this->p2 = p2;
}
```

And at least in the class Point all these member functions should be declared with qualifier const

```
double getXCoord() const;
double getYCoord() const;
double distanceTo(const Point&) const;
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> p2.setXCoord(double);       // <-- error
> p2.setYCoord(double);       // <-- error
> ```

`double` is a type, not a valid actual parameter name.

Call those functions with a value or a variable that is `double` or at least convertible to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

`double` is a reserved keyword for the double type, it can't be passed to a function as an argument, you need to forward the actual values from the Point type.

```
void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point p1) {
   p1.setXCoord(p1.getXCoord());   
   p1.setYCoord(p1.getYCoord());   
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry for the follow-up, but when I change my code to this I get the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)".  Am I doing something else wrong too then?

Comment: @Jamie_Q well the version of setEnd1 that you posted was being called recursively (don't call setEnd1 again at the end). That may be it, or it may be something completely different, there's no way to know from what you've posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
void LineSegment::setEnd1(Point p1) {
   p1.setXCoord(double);       // <-- error
   p1.setYCoord(double);       // <-- error
   setEnd1(p1);
}
```

LineSegment's set functions each take one argument of class Point. So when you give it a variable of type Point, you must save it as point.

```
void Point::setXCoord(double x) {
   xCoord = x;
}
```

This bit of your code is the template for what you want to do. Instead of type double, you want type Point for p1 and whatever the destination is called.